# How to make it from top ? (Cocoa sheet)

Tags: macos, cocoa, nspanel

I have implemented my sheet (NSPanel) with the following method:

```
- (void)showInWindow:(NSWindow *)mainWindow {
if (!finestra1)
    [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"XibName" owner:self];

[NSApp beginSheet:finestra1 modalForWindow:mainWindow modalDelegate:nil didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:nil];
[NSApp runModalForWindow:finestra1];   //This call blocks the execution until [NSApp stopModal] is called
```

}

The sheet is appearing in the middle of my screen, how to attach it to the top of my main window and make it appear with a "slide down" effect instead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried simply removing the `-runModalForWindow:` line?

Comment: Not working ... If you want I can upload my app but it would be hard to understand...

Comment: As in, it gave the same result as what you have?

Comment: Without that and with the NSBundle same result , Without both nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

[The way I was taught](http://books.google.com/books?id=_Kdf-wDBQ48C&lpg=PA335&ots=mE8kVRiQ9P&dq=%22endSheet%3AspeedSheet%22&pg=PA329#v=onepage&q&f=false), the sheet you're presenting should be an NSWindow, not an NSPanel.

Let me know if you'd like me to upload a simple demo project.

Comment: All panels are windows, so it is valid to begin a sheet that is a panel.